# Condition based selecting from group_concat in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Here is my table and sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` 
(
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tags` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `article_tags` 
(
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Wap Stories'),
(2, 'App Stories');

INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'USA'),
(2, 'England'),
(3, 'Germany'),
(4, 'India'),
(5, 'France'),
(6, 'Dubai'),
(7, 'Poland'),
(8, 'Japan'),
(9, 'China'),
(10, 'Australia');

INSERT INTO `article_tags` (`article_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(4, 1),
(5, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 1),
(6, 2),
(7, 2),
(8, 1),
(9, 1),
(3, 2),
(9, 2),
(10, 2);
```

How can I get the below output I have tried using group_concat function. It gives all the results. But my requirement is I need to groupconcat values as

**a**. Combination of 1,2 can be there, only 1 can be there but 2 alone cannot be there.

**b**. Combination of 2,1 can be there, only 2 can be there but 1 alone cannot be there

**Below is the output I need**

```
id, title,    groupconcat
--------------------------
1,  USA,      1,2
2,  England,  1,2
4,  India,    1
5,  France,   1
8,  Japan,    1
9,  China,    1,2
```

[SqlFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e02ce/1)

The query which I am using is

```
select id, title, group_concat(tag_id order by tag_id) as 'groupconcat' from articles a
left join article_tags att on a.id = att.article_id
where att.tag_id in (1,2)
group by article_id order by id
```

Comment: I don't get your requirements. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I need to get the tag ids of the countries which are tagged in. As in the above output you can see USA, England belongs to tag id 1 and 2 which is stored in tags table. So basically I need all the countries who are tagged to tag id 1 if they are tagged to tag id 1 then I also need to check whether they are tagged to tag id 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
SELECT id, title, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id) AS 'groupconcat' 
FROM articles a
LEFT join article_tags att on a.id = att.article_id
WHERE att.tag_id in (1,2)
GROUP BY article_id 
HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(groupconcat,',',1) !='2'
ORDER BY id
```